# Displaying Data from SQL Server database in an ASP.NET table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

From searching the internet for a short time I was able to write this code for an internal application I will be developing using Visual Studio ASP.NET / C#.

I am calling the database and creating a connection and then building a dropdown selection from the SQL code used.

Being very new to C# I am struggling to bring other fields into my table (e.g. Text strings and numbers and not just having a drop down field.

Ideally I'd like to show data like:

```
Activity | Hazards | Controls | RiskLevel(Dropdown)|
```

Here is my front end code:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="960" BorderWidth="3" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="ActivityID" Width="20%">Activity</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="HazardsID">Hazards</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="RiskID" Width="15%">Risk Level</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>

    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" >
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="lblActivity" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="lblHazards" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableFooterRow  runat="server" >
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Italic="true">
            INSERT **TEXTBOX FOR OTHER INFORMATION ATTACHED HERE!**
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableFooterRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Here is my current back end code:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1000 [MainActivityID],[ID],[Activity],[Hazards],CASE WHEN [Risk_Level] LIKE 'H' THEN 'HIGH' WHEN [Risk_Level] LIKE 'M' THEN 'MEDIUM' WHEN [Risk_Level] LIKE 'L' THEN 'LOW' WHEN[Risk_Level] LIKE 'T' THEN 'TRIVIAL' WHEN[Risk_Level] LIKE 'N' THEN 'N/A' END AS[Risk_Level],[Controls] FROM [STRIDES_SQL].[dbo].[STRIDES_RA_Activities]"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            ddl1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddl1.DataTextField = "Risk_Level";
            ddl1.DataValueField = "MainActivityID";
            ddl1.DataBind();
            String input = lblActivity.Text;
            con.Close();

        }
    }
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Risk Level--", "0"));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `Close` the connection, you're already `Dispose`ing it through that `using` scope.

Comment: That said, what's the question?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'd like to display text within fields as well as the dropdown i already have.

Comment: You should read up on things like the *repository pattern* and *separation of concerns*. That code, with intertwined view and business logic, is going to be very hard to write unit tests for. What's the `input` variable for? It's declared, assigned, and then discarded.

Comment: The single most fundamental thing in ASP.NET is the *page life cycle*. If we don't know where in that life cycle you're running that code, your question is unanswerable.